Besides trivial solution, are there $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=A+B$?
Putting apart the case in which $A$ and $B$ are the $\textbf{0}$ matrix, I believe that there are no other solutions to $AB=A+B$, but I am struggling to give a general proof to that. Moreover, after a possible proof is there a nice geometric interpretation to understand why?

False: Take $A=B=(2)$

Your equation is the same as $A(B-\mathbb 1)=B$ which has solutions whenever $B-\mathbb 1$ is invertible.  Note: by $\mathbb 1$ I mean the relevant identity matrix.

If you mean in integers the only solutions are $(a,b)=(0,0) \lor (2,2)$ If we are talking about real numbers any pair s.t $b=\frac{a}{a-1}$ , $a \neq 1$ is a solution

$(A-I)(B-I) = I$

Note:  In what follows, it is assumed that $A,B$ are square matrices of the same rank.
Letting $\mathbb 1$ denote the relevant identity matrix, we can rewrite your equation as $$A(B-\mathbb 1)=B$$
Thus, whenever $B$ is such that $(B-\mathbb 1)$ is invertible, we get a solution by taking $A=B(B-\mathbb 1)^{-1}$.
Phrased differently, for any invertible matrix $C$ we get the solution $$((C+\mathbb 1)C^{-1},C)=(C^{-1}+\mathbb 1, C+\mathbb 1)$$
For the one dimensional problem in particular, the solutions are $(\frac b{b-1},b)$ for all $b\neq 1$.

May be you can write $(C+1)C^{-1}$ as $C^{-1}+1$, so the solution looks simpler.

If I say $AB^{-1}=A-I$, will I be wrong? Then we'll get $$(A+B)(A-I)=I\implies A^2-(A+B)+AB=I\implies A^2=I$$ Is this correct?

@jjagmath  I agree, will edit.

@Gwen  where does $(A+B)(A-\mathbb 1)=\mathbb 1$ come from?   In one dimension, the pair $(A,B)=(2,2)$ is a solution,  since $4=2+2$, but we don't have $(2+2)(2-1)=1$.

Oh alright it was a misunderstanding of my notation. I don't know I had some brain fade leading to me thinking $AB^{-1}$ is the same as $(AB)^{-1}$

@Gwen  no worries.

@CroCo  agreed.  I'll edit to include that.

Rearranging $AB=A+B$ we get
$$
(A - I)(B - I) = I,
$$
where $I$ is the identity mtarix. Thus, $A - I$ and $B - I$ are both invertible. Therefore, the complete set of solutions is
$$
\Big\{ \; A = I + X, \; B = I + X^{-1} \; \mid \; X \text{ is invertible.} \Big\}
$$

Your conjecture is not true as @jjagmath and @lulu already noted in comments, and it's easy to see immediately if you limit yourself to ordinary numbers (which you can think of as 1x1 matrices):
You are looking for numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $ab=a+b$. This equation can be transformed to $a(b-1)=b$ or $a = b/(b-1)$. So for every $b\ne 1$, there is such an $a$: For example: For $b=2$ we get $a=2$ and indeed $2*2=2+2$.  For $b=3$ we get $a=1.5$, and indeed $3*1.5=3+1.5$.
We can do exactly the same for non-1x1 matrices: If $AB=A+B$, you can transform this to $A(B-I)=B$, and if $B-I$ is invertable (the matrix version of something you divide by - like we had $\ne 0$ for numbers), you get $A = B(B-I)^{-1}$. So picking any matrix such as $B-I$ is invertable will get you a pair $A$,$B$ that falsifies your conjecture.
